# How can I get rows in table to align vertically when some rows have emojis and some rows do not?

Tags: html, css, emoji

I have an html page utilizing flex-box and a table which has text rows, in which some contain emojis and some do not.  I have been unsuccessful thus far getting the rows to align vertically, such that all rows are centered vertically.

I have tried various combinations of margin and padding to no avail.

In the code provided you will see that rows without emojis are at the top and the ones with emojis are centered.  If I make the rows without emojis centered, the rows with emojis are at the bottom. My goal is to have all rows properly centered vertically within the row under all cases.

```css
 .wrapper1 {
  max-height: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
 }
 .wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
 }
 .wrapper3 {
  max-height:150px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .sm_table_header {
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  border-top-left-radius:4px;
  border-top-right-radius:4px;
  color:#ffffff;
  background-color: #307eab;
  height: 20px;
 }
 .sm_table_row {
  height: 25px;
  display: flex;           display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;     -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 0;            -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;         -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper1">
 <div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="wrapper3">
   <div class="sm_table_header ui-widget-header">
    <div class="sm_table_row">
     <div class="sm_table_subject_head">Subject</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper3">
   <div class="sm_table_body">  
  <div class="sm_table_row" id="1">
   <div class="sm_table_subject">Test Emoji </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sm_table_row" id="1">
   <div class="sm_table_subject">test 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sm_table_row" id="1">
   <div class="sm_table_subject"><span class="span.emoji" style="></span>"Test Emoji 2 <span class="span.emoji"></span> - good deal</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sm_table_row" id="1">
   <div class="sm_table_subject">Test Emoji 2 <span class="span.emoji"></span> - good deal</div>
  </div>     
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set the line-height for .sm_table_row, will center each element perfectly.

```
.sm_table_row {
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

```css
.wrapper1 {
  max-height: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
 }
 .wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
 }
 .wrapper3 {
  max-height:150px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .sm_table_header {
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  border-top-left-radius:4px;
  border-top-right-radius:4px;
  color:#ffffff;
  background-color: #307eab;
  height: 20px;
 }
 .sm_table_row {
  height: 25px;
  display: flex;           display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;     -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 0;            -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;         -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
  border-collapse: collapse;
    line-height: 25px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper1">
 <div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="wrapper3">
   <div class="sm_table_header ui-widget-header">
    <div class="sm_table_row">
     <div class="sm_table_subject_head">Subject</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper3">
   <div class="sm_table_body">  
  <div class="sm_table_row" id="1">
   <div class="sm_table_subject">Test Emoji </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sm_table_row" id="1">
   <div class="sm_table_subject">test 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sm_table_row" id="1">
   <div class="sm_table_subject"><span class="span.emoji" style="></span>"Test Emoji 2 <span class="span.emoji"></span> - good deal</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sm_table_row" id="1">
   <div class="sm_table_subject">Test Emoji 2 <span class="span.emoji"></span> - good deal</div>
  </div>     
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I have struggled with this for 2 hours.  It worked perfect.

Comment: try setting the line height to 100px for example...
this only works when line-height == height

Answer (score 1):

on `.sm_table_row` use

```
align-items: center;
```

"Flex items can be aligned in the cross axis of the current line of the flex container, similar to justify-content but in the perpendicular direction. align-items sets the default alignment for all of the flex container’s items, including anonymous flex items."
- flexbox cheatsheet: https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/#align-items

```css
    .wrapper1 {
        max-height: 200px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        padding-right: 25px;
        padding-left: 25px;
    }
    .wrapper2 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
    .wrapper3 {
        max-height:150px;
        overflow: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .sm_table_header {
        display:flex; 
        flex-direction: column;
        border-top-left-radius:4px;
        border-top-right-radius:4px;
        color:#ffffff;
        background-color: #307eab;
        height: 20px;
    }
    .sm_table_row {
        height: 25px;
        display: flex;           display: -webkit-flex;
        flex-direction: row;     -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        flex-grow: 0;            -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
        flex-wrap: wrap;         -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 100%;
        align-items: center;
        border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">

<div class="wrapper1">
    <div class="wrapper2">
        <div class="wrapper3">
            <div class="sm_table_header ui-widget-header">
                <div class="sm_table_row">
                    <div class="sm_table_subject_head">Subject</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper3">
            <div class="sm_table_body">     
        <div class="sm_table_row" id="1">
            <div class="sm_table_subject">Test Emoji </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sm_table_row" id="1">
            <div class="sm_table_subject">test 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sm_table_row" id="1">
            <div class="sm_table_subject"><span class="span.emoji" style="></span>"Test Emoji 2 <span class="span.emoji"></span> - good deal</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sm_table_row" id="1">
            <div class="sm_table_subject">Test Emoji 2 <span class="span.emoji"></span> - good deal</div>
        </div>                  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, but removed the lines between rows.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Tim I can still see the lines... Do you maybe have scaling factor < 100% in your browser? maybe its a screen rendering issue?